# USB tethering with Cyanogenmod 7.0.3

Tags: cyanogenmod, usb, tethering

How do I enable USB tethering with Cyanogenmod 7.0.3 and Ubuntu Lucid?

http://oldwiki.cyanogenmod.org/index.php?title=Tethering mentions *Settings » Wireless & networks » Tethering » USB tethering*, but there is no such option *Tethering*.

With http://code.google.com/p/android-wired-tether/ the phone application says that I have a bad kernel (on the phone). `ifconfig` on the laptop doesn't show `usb0`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The built-in tethering should be `Settings->Wireless and Network->Tethering & portable hotspot->USB tethering`. I think the name of the menu simply changed between CM6 and CM7 from "Tethering" to "Tethering & portable hotspot".

**Edit:** Additionally, it appears that some phones are simply not supported due to kernel issues. For these devices, the menu option will not be present. [This thread](http://forum.cyanogenmod.com/topic/18868-missing-usb-tethering/) on the CyanogenMod forums discusses this, and notes at least two devices which fall into this category (the HTC Tattoo and the ZTE Blade).